# Vectorizing the python cycle using NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, numerical-methods

For the reason of my math modelling, I have a vector_U function

```
import numpy as np
def vector_U(U_0, t, func, dt):
    res = np.empty((len(t), 4))
    res[0] = U_0
    for i in range(1, len(t)):
        res[i] = res[i-1]+runge_kutta(res[i-1], t[i-1], func, dt)
    return res
```

where func is the function `f([x, y, vx, vy]) = [vx, vy, ax, ay]` of the differential equation and runge_kutta is

```
def runge_kutta(x, t, func, dt):
    k1 = dt*func(x, t)
    k2 = dt*func(x+k1/2, t+dt/2)
    k3 = dt*func(x+k2/2, t+dt/2)
    k4 = dt*func(x+k3, t+dt)
    return (k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)/6
```

The purpose of the vector_U function is to take the 4-vector of starting conditions U_0 and t=np.linspace(0, t_final, t_final/dt) and return the array of the 4-vectors for each dt step. Then x = res[0] and y = res[1] columns are used for animation.

While it works fine, for a large t (e.g. `len(t)==50000`) the function obviously becomes slow just because it uses cycles. Since I am trying (instead of KISS, yes) make the program as much vectorized as possible to make it work faster, does the NumPy have any method to vectorize something like that? I don't mean the specific decision but the way to vectorize loops such as this because, I assume, I don't understand the vectorization method completely.

I thought about using np.cumsum of runge_kuttas... but for each runge_kutta I still need a previous value of U.

Comment: "slow just because it uses cycles" - do you mean because it uses *loops*?

Comment: Is there a reason you're writing the integration yourself rather than using `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp`?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Ouch. I'm sorry, I am not a native English, thanks for the correction!

@jared Mostly it's just a whim, but I tried to test `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp` and it returned the result (for f(U) being the equation of the orbital motion) with the quite a big error already after one revolution around the star. While self-written RK4 has unexpectedly turned out to be much more accurate and unlike the scipy's one hasn't turned an ellipse into a spiral. I still don't know how it works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For code like this, Numba is a great way to speed it up.  Here's a quick guide: https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/5minguide.html

You can basically keep your code as-is, add a decorator (or wrapper function) and get a pretty good speedup, sometimes comparable to what you'd get with NumPy vectorized code.